# How to organize an extra grid tier

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to customize the grid like this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid

Namely I want to add a grid option (namely, xxs).

I've created custom.css:

```
 $grid-breakpoints: (
  xxs: 0,
  xs: 375px,
  sm: 576px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 992px,
  xl: 1200px,
  xxl: 1400px
);

$container-max-widths: (  
  xxs: 330px,
  xs: 505px,
  sm: 540px,
  md: 720px,
  lg: 960px,
  xl: 1140px,
  xxl: 1320px
);

@import "bootstrap-5.0.0-beta1/scss/bootstrap";
```

An extra media request really appeared. And this xxs breakpoint really works for a container width. Please, have a look at the picture.

[image]

But it is not a grid tier, if I'm not mistaken. This code doesn't work:

This
    ‍

col-xxs-1 just doesn't work. I checked the css generated during the compilation. Namely I try to find "xxs" there. There is only two cases. And they are all about .container-xxs. Pictures are attached.
[image]
[image]

So, columns will not react on col-xxs.

Could you help me understand whether it is possible at all. And if it is, how to organize an extra grid tier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine, but remember that you're replacing the "default" tier `xs` with `xxs`, therefore `xxs` becomes the new implied breakpoint and won't use an infix. New classed for `col-xs-*` will be added. For example...

`col-1` (xxs)
`col-xs-1` (xs)

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/lxLwfdH7Xj#)